# Performance Evaluation of Employee didn't fetch the data in database

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently developing Human Resource Management System. I have HR admin user and have a specific dashboard for him. In his dashboard, he can write performance evaluation for his employees. My problem is on Employee's Dashboard (another user) I want that if employees click the evaluation button it will automatically fetch his performance evaluation written by HR Admin. Note his evaluation only, not by other employee.

This is my code below

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement

Public Class UserDashboard
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-995ANIF\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=IMhrmDB;User ID=hrmDB;Password=bsis_IM")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sd As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Public Property LoggedInEmployeeID As String


    'EVALUATION
    Private Sub btnUserEvaluation_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUserEvaluation.Click
        UserTabControl.SelectedTab = TabPage5
        ShowPerformanceReview(LoggedInEmployeeID)
    End Sub

    'Method to display the performance review for the logged-in employee
    Private Sub ShowPerformanceReview(employeeID As String)
        'Authenticate the user to ensure they're an employee (use your own authentication logic)
        If IsEmployeeLoggedIn() Then
            'Retrieve the performance review based on employee ID
            Dim performanceReview As String = RetrievePerformanceReview(employeeID)

            'Display the performance review in the employee's dashboard
            ShowReviewInDashboard(performanceReview)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function IsEmployeeLoggedIn() As Boolean
        ' Implement your authentication logic here to validate if the user is an employee
        ' You can compare the logged-in user ID with your employee records
        ' Return True if the user is an employee, else False
        ' Example:
        ' Return If(LoggedInEmployeeID <> 0, True, False)
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LoggedInEmployeeID) 'Replace this with your logic
    End Function

    Private Function RetrievePerformanceReview(employeeID As String) As String
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeEvaluation WHERE EmployeeID = @Employee_ID"

        'Execute the query and retrieve the review for that employee
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-995ANIF\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=IMhrmDB;User ID=hrmDB;Password=bsis_IM")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", employeeID)
                con.Open()
                Dim performancereview As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                con.Close()

                If performancereview IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return performancereview.ToString()
                Else
                    Return "No employee evaluation available."
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub ShowReviewInDashboard(reviewText As String)
        ' Display the retrieved review on the employee's dashboard
        ' Update a label, text box, or any UI element with the reviewText
        ' Example: lblEvaluation.Text = reviewText

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", LoggedInEmployeeID)

            'Open the database connection
            con.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.Read() Then
            tbxEvalEmployeeID.Text = LoggedInEmployeeID
            tbxEvalDepartment.Text = reader("EmployeeFullName").ToString()
            tbxEvalEmployeeName.Text = reader("Department").ToString()
            tbxEvalPosition.Text = reader("Position").ToString()

            lblEvalScore1.Text = reader("WorkQuality").ToString()
            lblEvalScore2.Text = reader("ExecutionProgress").ToString()
            lblEvalScore3.Text = reader("ProblemSolving").ToString()
            lblEvalScore4.Text = reader("Adaptability").ToString()
            lblEvalScore5.Text = reader("PlanningOrganization").ToString()
            lblEvalTOTALScore.Text = reader("Total").ToString()
            tbxEvalFeedback.Text = reader("Recommendation").ToString()
            lblEvaluatorName.Text = reader("Evaluator").ToString()
            lblDateOfEvaluation.Text = reader("EvaluationDate").ToString()
        Else
            'If no employee is found for the provided ID, show a message or clear labels
            MessageBox.Show("Employee not found.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetLoggedInEmployeeID() As Integer
        'Replace this function with your actual logic to retrieve the logged-in employee ID
        Return LoggedInEmployeeID
    End Function
End Class
```

This is code is running but when I am already logged into employees' dashboard and when I click the evaluation button it errors, and it emphasizes this line of code

```
Dim performancereview As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

And it says "Invalid Column Name"

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT *` if you're calling `ExecuteScalar`? The whole point of `ExecuteScalar` is to get one value so you should be specifying one column. As for the issue, the only column you're specifying in that query is `EmployeeID` in the `WHERE` clause, so it sounds like that must be the invalid column name. If you omit the `WHERE` clause, does the query execute successfully?